# Postman - call login and repeat request if response code is 401

Tags: rest, postman

I have many requests in a Postman collection. Most of them expect user to be authenticated.
There is also "login" request that authenticates a user.

Login request:

`POST {{API_URL}}auth/token/`

payload:

```
{
    "email": "{{email}}",
    "password": "{{password}}"
}
```

I want any request that ended up with `401` response to call the `login` request above and repeat itself.

Is that possible?

I could probably add `pre-request` script that mimics the `login` request but I'd need to add it to each request in the collection (hundreds) and also it would be called before each request (redundant).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
You only need to add it to the pre-request script at the collection level (root folder) and it will be called before each request. This is the solution I've adopted, but you are correct, it is redundant.

Option 2:
You could also use postman.setNextRequest(), **however this only works for the postman runner** (and Newman I think). If that is you're use case you could add this to your test script at the collection level:

```
if(pm.response.code === 401){
    pm.environment.set("returnTo", "<name of this request>");
    postman.setNextRequest("<name of auth request>");
}
```

Then in the test tab of your auth request you could add:

```
postman.setNextRequest(pm.environment.get("returnTo"));
```